# "Задайте нам вопрос, и если нам хватит ума, мы на него ответим в журнале". Запятые

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложении:

> Задайте нам вопрос, и если нам хватит ума, мы на него ответим в
>   журнале.

Взято на [сайте ТЖ](https://journal.tinkoff.ru/about/).

Мне кажется, правильно так:

> Задайте нам вопрос и, если нам хватит ума, мы на него ответим в
>   журнале.

Первую запятую, мне кажется, ставить не нужно (сложносочинённое предложение, обе части равноправны), а вот ещё одной не хватает — для того, чтобы отделить "если нам хватит ума".

Кстати, тут можно было бы и скобки поставить:

> Задайте нам вопрос и (если нам хватит ума) мы на него ответим в
>   журнале.

Я к ТЖ никак не отношусь, просто слышал, что там тщательно проверяют материалы, и пытаюсь понять: у них ляп или у меня нехватка знаний.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) Задайте нам вопрос, и, **если нам хватит ума,** мы на него ответим в журнале.

(2) Задайте нам вопрос, и **если нам хватит ума, то мы на него ответим в журнале.**

Первая запятая перед союзом И обозначает сочинительную связь между двумя предикативными основами и ставится обязательно: **Задайте** нам вопрос, и **мы** на него **ответим** в журнале.

Обособление придаточного делается в случае союза ЕСЛИ и не делается в случае двойного союза ЕСЛИ...ТО. Во втором варианте сложноподчиненное предложение рассматривается как единое целое.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Вариант со скобками:

Задайте нам вопрос, и (если нам хватит ума) мы на него ответим в журнале.

Такое оформление возможно, но это будет  **особо подчеркнутое выделение** вида "если нам, **конечно,** хватит ума".

Comment: По-моему, исчерпывающий ответ по части запятых.  Но там  еще предлагалось поставить скобки. Думаю ответ таков: это не запрещено, но неуместно в данном случае (слишком акцентированное выделение).

Comment: Если уж разговор зашел о достаточности ума, то это особый стиль общения с читателями, а в этом случае (в отличие от нейтрального стиля) всё возможно.

Comment: Это даже особый вид корпоративной самокритичности - открыто высказываемое сомнение в достаточности совокупного ума для ответа в журнале :)

Answer (score 2):

Пример, который вы приводите, представляет собой сложное предложение с разными видами связи: сочинением и подчинением. Пунктуационное оформление таких предложений (на стыке союзов) зависит того, следует ли после первого союза  вторая часть двойного союза, **напр.: если...то.**

> Ср.: Задайте нам вопрос, и, если нам хватит ума, мы на него ответим в журнале.
>     Задайте нам вопрос, и **если** нам хватит ума, **то** мы на него ответим в журнале. **Запятая не ставится, т. к. дальше следует вторая часть двойного союза то**.

**В первом предложении (между рядом стоящими подчинительными союзами стоит запятая) вторую придаточную часть можно изъять или переставить в другое место без нарушения структуры предложения. Во втором предложении этого сделать нельзя, так как с изъятием или перестановкой второй придаточной части рядом окажутся слова что…то, а такое соседство нарушает стилистические нормы литературного языка.**

> Ср. также: **Мечик почувствовал, что, если вновь придётся отстреливаться, он уже ничем не будет отличаться от Пики (Ф.); Я уже подумал, что если в сию решительную минуту не переспорю старика, то уже впоследствии трудно мне будет освобождаться от его опеки (П.).**

См.: [Розенталь. Д.Э. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140)

Comment: Серж, а у Вас запятая перед союзом И не ставится?

Comment: @ Jasmin, да, конечно, запятая нужна, механически скопировал и не поставил запятую.

Comment: @Серж Так все же — нужна запятая перед союзом И?

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, если дальше не следует часть двойного союза, запятая ставится перед союзом и.  Если нет, то запятая ставится дважды: перед союзом и после.См. примеры.

Comment: Это-то как раз и понятно. Просто у Вас в одном примере была запятая **перед И**, а в другом — нет. А править Ваш ответ я не решилась.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, просто механически скопировал и не заметил отсутствие запятых. Спасибо за поправку!